# qttorch Build Error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: build, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, qmake

I'm trying to install **qttorch package** on Ubuntu 14.04,
but I get this error during installation:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:626 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" but
  QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:634 (message):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /tmp/luarocks_qtlua-scm-1-2765/qtlua/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for
  more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:38 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/luarocks_qtlua-scm-1-2765/qtlua/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/qtlua-scm-1.rockspec - Build error: Failed building.
```

Is **libqtcore4** the right package for QTCore? or is there another package that should be installed?

because it's already installed in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" as qmake reported!

I also tried reinstalling it, but still the same error!!

Answer (score 3):

In most Linux distributions the packages are split between development and none-development parts. Usually the normal package only includes the shared library, data and executables while the dev package adds headers, static libraries and build tools like qmake. I assume this split is done to save space.

For ubuntu the dev packages usually has the `-dev` suffix. So try if a libqtcore4-dev package exists. Otherwise, libqt4-dev should include it.